# java.net.BindException when creating datagram socket in Android on Mac

Tags: java, android

I am creating one datagram socket in my application like below:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(60000,
                        InetAddrByName("192.168.1.72"));
```

This datagram constructor returns with exception

```
java.net.BindException: The requested address could not be bound.
```

I have added the android.permission.INTERNET to my manifest file. I am using iMac and Eclipse 3.4.2. I checked that port 60000 is free. Also 192.168.1.72 is my ip address. So what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

from the dev site
**Referring to localhost from the emulated environment**

*If you need to refer to your host computer's localhost, such as when you want the emulator client to contact a server running on the same host, use the alias 10.0.2.2 to refer to the host computer's loopback interface. From the emulator's perspective, localhost (127.0.0.1) refers to its own loopback interface.*

Comment: I just want to bind my socket to my ethernet IP address. Else I will handle.

Answer (score 0):

What do mean by "my ip address".

This is one of the addresses you see when you enumerate the NetworkInterface instances ON THE device?

Comment: I mean my Ethernet IP address. And it is as specified in the code snippet.

Comment: well, this comment does not contain a single bit of information more or less than your original. It is not useful if you want your question to be answered. We try to help you by removing uncertainty, then decide if we can help or if we don't know, either. Actually there is much uncertainty: do you run on the device or the emulator? The ip address is the address of the (emulated or not) device or the target address. As i don't know your level of proficiency, such questions might be valid.

Comment: I am running app in emulator only.